# How can I make FTP access from the web working?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, ubuntu, ftp

I am in a VPS environment.
I am using Ubuntu 10.04LTS, apache2.2.4, php 5.3.2 and vsftpd for ftp service.

If user connects to the server with ftp program, everything works fine.

However, If user tries to install something from the webpage using ftp (for example, drupal modules installation from the web) things do not work.

Apache is currently run by user called 'www-data'

Each user belongs to the group of their own username. (For example, user with username 'joe' belongs to the group called 'joe'... is it okay? or do I have to put them all in 'users' group?)

If seems that, some user is saying that after they try updating , some of their web directory folders' permission have changed into 'www-data.'

Also, getting directory listing from the web(PHP) by typing ftp information seems to work fine... It just that if user wants server to connect to some address, download tar.gz file, and install automatically, it does not work.

How can I make FTP access from the web(PHP) working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself...
It was problem related with IPv6 setting. I could not connect to 'localhost' with IPv6 settings turned on.

I had to edit /etc/hosts file and commented the IPv6 related lines... for me they were bottom 5 lines.

Now I can connect to localhost and everything works fine.